# Does enabling LLVM's MemorySanitizer change the ABI of libraries

Tags: clang, llvm, abi, address-sanitizer, memory-sanitizer

The LLVM projects MemorySanitizer has a somewhat difficult to satisfy constraint that all system libraries must also be built with MemorySanitizer.

I've been thinking about some ways to enable MSAN for a project I'm working on (it already uses ASAN and UBSAN), specifically with respect to this constraint. One possible solution I've been considering would result in a situation where when the project was compiled with `-fsanitize=memory`, it would link against non-instrumented versions of dynamic system libraries like `libc`, and `libstdc++`, and, say `libcrypto` (to add one that isn't really part of the 'toolchain'). But then at runtime, the instrumented binary would run in a special environment (basically a different userspace) where all of the system dynamic libraries had been built with `-fsanitize=memory`.

Is such a scheme viable? It seems to me that it depends on whether building a library with `-fsanitize=memory` alters its ABI, because if the library ABI differs between the instrumented and non-instrumented versions, then the image built against the non-instrumented system dynamic libraries is going to fail catastrophically at runtime when started up in the environment with the instrumented system libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the library ABI differs between the instrumented and non-instrumented versions, then the image built against the non-instrumented system dynamic libraries is going to fail catastrophically at runtime

First of all, compiling with `-fsanitize=memory` *does* change ABI e.g. by adding additional (shadow) operands to function calls. This means that combining sanitized and non-sanitized code *at runtime* will likely crash.

On the other hand, Msan does *not* change link-time library ABI i.e. it does not change symbol sizes or names so external interface of library (i.e. contents of it's ELF symbol table) compiled with `-fsanitize=memory` does not change.

This means that *linking* against non-sanitized version and later *running* with sanitized one is ok.

Comment: I don't think that can be right. If your application was compiled against `libx.so` with one ABI, and then you dropped in a new version of `libx.so` with a different ABI the application certainly might crash at runtime, or at best misbehave. Imagine if the size, alignment, or layout of a type defined by `libx.so` has changed between those ABIs, and your application makes use of those types in communication with `libx.so`?

Comment: @acm It's important to distinguish compile-time and runtime parts of ABI here. I've updated my answer to hopefully make this point clear.

Comment: OK, that clarification helps, and if that is the case then it sounds like my approach is at least potentially viable. Do you happen to know of any technical documentation that supports this as something like an MSAN design goal? I't would be disappointing to build my solution around this, only to find that future versions of LLVM no longer work this way.

Comment: @acm Unfortunately I don't. Msan is not really usable much outside of Google due to design constraints you outlined so very few people experiment with it.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. One small thing: did you mean `-fsanitize=memory` above? You have `-fsanitize=address`. Just checking. I plan to accept your answer.

Comment: @acm Yes, sorry. Too much Asan usage at work) BTW Asn is quite different from Msan in that it actually allows _partial_ program sanitization.

Comment: Yes, definitely aware of that re ASAN - this project already has ASAN and UBSAN integration in the CI loop, to great success. So now of course I want [M,T]SAN as well.

Comment: @acm It's a pity that security research community has focused on Asan until now. Hopefully they'll get to Msan at some point and provide us with Msan-enabled distro. After that the tool would finally be usable for general public.

Comment: My plan is more or less to use Docker and gentoo to make two Gentoo containers that are equivalent, except that one has `-fsanitize=memory` plumbed through the emerge CFLAGS. Then build the product to be tested in the "normal" image (so as not to pay the msan overhead for the compiler and build system) but with `-fsanitize=memory` applied. Then run the tests by transferring the instrumented build of the product into the instrumented runtime. I'll follow up here when I get to that project (a few months from now, realistically).

Comment: @acm Makes sense. Be sure to check similar work done for Asan ([here](http://injoit.org/index.php/j1/article/view/231) and [here](https://archive.fosdem.org/2016/schedule/event/csafecode/attachments/slides/1131/export/events/attachments/csafecode/slides/1131/fosdem_gentoo_asan.pdf)).